# How Can Compile Bind9 on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, dns, make, bind9

I am working on a dns configuration. I need to compile Bind 9. I am using Debian 11. I reviewed the documents and installed the necessary libraries, but not created "makefile". I am new to this field. So I thought you might be able to help. Do not hesitate to give ideas. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi, '...but I could not "make"' is not very helpful. Please add more detailed information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why do you need to compile ? If you do not need to modify source code or compilation options, it is way more simple to do a simple `apt-get install bind9` as described in [this documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9). If you give us more informations on why do you compile, and what is the error, we will try to help you, but we can't as we do not have enough informations now.

Comment: @mnille I solved the problem. A small package was giving an error while installing. I'm trying to run the compiled program named 'named'. Any ideas that can help?

Comment: @thiblcr I solved the problem. A small package was giving an error while installing. I'm trying to run the compiled program named 'named'. Any ideas that can help?